# QueryTables Method - irregular table size

Tags: vba, excel

I was handed a VBA macro written by someone else who no longer works for the company and asked to add additional functions. This macro uses the QueryTables method, which I am unfamiliar with, to import data from a fixed-width text file into Excel. The file has some basic information in the first row (date and time, recording number, etc.) and the actual data begins in the second row. The text file only has 4 columns and uses quotes to indicate where data for one sensor ends and another begins within that column. Example:

```
20140529 15:11:42 Rec# 0001                         
'SENSOR1         ''SENSOR2         ''SENSOR3         ''SENSOR4         ' 
 0.00000           1500.00           1.05400E-01      0.123799E-02             
0.100000           1510.00          -7.68900E-01      0.404716E-02             
'SENSOR5         ''SENSOR6         ''SENSOR7         ''SENSOR8         ' 
0.710000E-01      0.250000E-01       2.12500           1.87100                 
0.450000E-01      0.290000E-01       2.36200           2.19200
```

Originally, the macro would start importing at row 2, skipping over the title info and pasting each sensor in it's own column. Here's the original QueryTables code:

```
' Input Unigraph file
fileName = "TEXT;H:\ModeShapeData.input"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=fileName, _
    Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "ModeShapeData.input"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(18, 18, 18)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I changed the `.TextFileStartRow` value to 1 so that I would get the title info as well as the data, but it caused the data to be imported exactly as it looks in the text file rather than putting each sensor into its own column.

I can only assume that there's a simple way to get the title info imported, either by leaving this code alone and importing the first row seperately or by changing something in the With block to get more than 4 columns back.

**UPDATE**

I have found a work-around to the problem by leaving the original code as is and then creating an additional subroutine to do it again to a new sheet starting ay row 1 instead of row 2, and then I pull my info from that sheet instead of the Data sheet. I'll leave this here in case someone comes up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: @pnuts That would require manually editing the text file. I would rather the macro be able to handle it exaclty as it is (it is the product of a file export from a UNIX database).

Comment: @S M Perron I'm really curious to know how that querytable statement turns a 4 column csv into 8 columns.  I would suggest using the macro recorder, but that wouldn't mimic the 'new column for each sensor' trait, unless there's something big i'm missing.  All I can offer is this would be easy to mimic with a loop, but I hope you get a response on doing it with querytables

Comment: @Acantud I can't explain the column part either.